# How can i use CMake to generate Windows 10 universal project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to use CMake to generate Visual Studio 15 project c++ static library for Windows 10. It should be usable on phones so I think it should have support for windows store. 
Are there any flags I can set?

I've found https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake, it is Microsoft's fork of CMake, but I can't find a clue how to use it to enable uniwersal app support.

With "normal" cmake when i switch on support for windows stope I get an Error:

> error MSB3843: Project "project1" targets platform "Windows", but references SDK "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps v14.0" which targets platform "UAP".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0

Comment: One additional hint. With growing Windows 10 (sub)version numbers and littering of SDK versions, you might need to write something like 10.0.14393.0 instead of 10. Otherwise the desired C++ compiler might not be found.

Comment: 10.0 will select the latest installed SDK (with later cmake versions)

Answer (score 2):

The support for Universal Windows project is provided from cmake version 3.4.0 onwards. Older versions don't support it. The above command works with cmake 3.4.0.