# Generate universal windows platform solution and project files using CMake

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to generate solution and project files for a static library in universal windows platform using cmake. I gave parameters as specified in the other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857315/how-can-i-use-cmake-to-generate-windows-10-universal-project)

But it generated project files with incorrect configs (TargetPlatformVersion = 8.1 and WindowsStoreAppSupport=No). Instead the values should be like TargetPlatformVersion = 10.0.10586.0 or 10.0.10240.0 and WindowsStoreAppSupport = Yes.

I have given parameters as `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = WindowsStore` and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION = 10.0` and selected the generator to "Visual Studio 14 2015".

Is Universal Windows Platform supported by CMake? If yes, then how do I generate the project files supporting UWP?

Comment: Are you using the latest CMake 3.4 version? The newer the version, the higher the changes CMake supports such new developments.

Comment: I'm using cmake 3.3.1. Let me try cmake 3.4 and come back.

Comment: It worked out with CMake 3.4 version. Thanks! I would recommend to upgrade your comment as an answer to the question.

Comment: Official documentation: [Cross Compiling for Windows 10 Universal Applications](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-windows-10-universal-applications)

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of CMake support the newer version of Visual Studio and Windows 10 SDK. If you get weird errors, try updating to the lasted CMake version.